# Finding duplicate strings in array

Tags: php

guys! I have a database with IDs and names of my products. I need to find the different colors of each product - they're with duplicate names. I've tried so many things, but I still don't have any luck, since there might be 5+ colors of one product. It needs to be checked one row after another (since there might be a product in the beginning with the same name, which is not a different color, but a different product). Could someone help me, please? Thank you!

This:

```
array(
    0 => array('D41596', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ БЛУЗА ТРИКО'),
    1 => array('D41597', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ БЛУЗА ТРИКО С ПОЛА BALMAIN 5310'),
    2 => array('D41599', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ БЛУЗА ТРИКО С ПОЛА BALMAIN 5310'),
    3 => array('D41600', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ БЛУЗА С ПОЛА РАЕ 1736'),
    4 => array('D41601', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ БЛУЗА С ГАЩЕРИЗОН 613 НА БОЛИНКИ'),
    5 => array('D41602', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ БЛУЗА С ГАЩЕРИЗОН 613 НА БОЛИНКИ'),
    6 => array('D41603', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ БЛУЗА С ПАНТАЛОН 615'),
    7 => array('D41604', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ БЛУЗА С ПАНТАЛОН 615'),
    8 => array('D41605', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ КЪС ПАНТАЛОН С ТОП САТЕН'),
    9 => array('D41606', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ КЪС ПАНТАЛОН С ТОП САТЕН'),
    10 => array('D41607', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ КЪС ПАНТАЛОН С ТОП САТЕН'),
    11 => array('D41608', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ ДЪНКИ С БЛУЗА ТРИКО 062 ФЛАМИНГО'),
    12 => array('D41609', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ КЪС ДЪНКОВ ПАНТАЛОН С БЛУЗА ТРИКО 085 КОЛИБРИ'),
    13 => array('D41610', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ КЪС ДЪНКОВ ПАНТАЛОН С БЛУЗА ТРИКО 075 ЦВЕТЯ ОТ ПАЕТИ'),
    14 => array('D41611', 'ДАМСКИ КОМПЛЕКТ ДЪНКОВА ПОЛА С БЛУЗА ТРИКО 072 ЛИЛАВИ ЦВЕТЯ С ПАЕТИ')
);
```

Should output:

```
array(
    'D41597' => 'D41597,D41599',
    'D41599' => 'D41597,D41599',
    'D41601' => 'D41601,D41602',
    'D41602' => 'D41601,D41602',
    'D41603' => 'D41603,D41604',
    'D41604' => 'D41603,D41604',
    'D41605' => 'D41605,D41606,D41607',
    'D41606' => 'D41605,D41606,D41607',
    'D41607' => 'D41605,D41606,D41607'
);
```

Comment: can you post the code you ve tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick. Basically, it loops over the IDs and checks for  occurrences with the same name, then adds found item IDs to the results table:

```
$results = array();

foreach ($arr as $element) {

    list ($key, $value) = $element; 
    $searchResults = array();   

    foreach ($arr as $searchElement) {              
        if ($searchElement[1] == $value) {
            $searchResults[] = $searchElement[0];
        }
    }

    if (sizeof($searchResults) > 1) {
        $results[$key] = implode(',', $searchResults);
    }       
}

print_r($results);

Array
(
    [D41597] => D41597,D41599
    [D41599] => D41597,D41599
    [D41601] => D41601,D41602
    [D41602] => D41601,D41602
    [D41603] => D41603,D41604
    [D41604] => D41603,D41604
    [D41605] => D41605,D41606,D41607
    [D41606] => D41605,D41606,D41607
    [D41607] => D41605,D41606,D41607
)
```

Comment: Ohhh... thank you so much for your time... It will be so much easier than manually doing this in Excel... :-)))